# VBA to Open MS Access Form Full Screen

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have problem with VBA Access database I want to open form full screen. 
Let me know which property and code I use to do fix the issue.

I tried many script and codes.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Application.Forms = Xlmaximized
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a form to maximize it is:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    DoCmd.Maximize

End Sub
```

The application you should never force to be maximize. That would be to violate the user's control over the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you would like to violiate the user's control over the machine and maximize the application, you could do this too:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    DoCmd.Maximize
    Application.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize

End Sub
```